# Axios with Reactjs Bad Request when posting my data

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs

I got error `BadRequest 400` when trying to post data to the web api using react and axios library, here is my code:

```js
let token = 'xxx-token';
let username = 'username';
export const PostData = (url, formData) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        instance.post(`${config.externalApi}/${url}`, formData, { 
            headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`, "X-Default-Username": username, "Content-Type": "application/json" }
         }).then(response => {
            if(response.data !== undefined && response.data !== null) {
                resolve(response.data);
            } else {
                reject(Error('no data found'))
            }
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    })
}
```

**Sample Payload Data**

```json
{
    "companyId": 1286,
    "postingDate": "2021-04-27T05:20:39.253Z",
    "startDate": "2021-06-08T05:20:39.000Z",
    "endDate": "2021-04-27T05:20:39.253Z",
    "makePlacementDate": "2021-04-27T05:20:39.253Z",
    "closingDate": "2021-04-27T05:20:39.253Z",
    "inDeclare": true,
    "positionType": "Internship",
    "jobTitle": "Software Engineer Intern",
    "department": "IT Department",
    "noOfPositions": "5",
    "internshipPlacementType": "1",
    "ihlLevel": "3",
    "duration": "4 Months and 15 Days",
    "jobFunction": "9",
    "rolesAndResponsibility": "Roles and Responsibilities",
    "scopeAndOutcomes": "Learning Outcomes and Objectives",
    "skillsAndKnowledge": "Requirements",
    "actionModeType": "Submit",
    "resourceSumitId": null,
    "remarks": "",
    "recipient": "",
    "remarksBy": ""
}
```

**My Controller**

```cs
        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost("jobposition/create")]
        public IActionResult AddJobPosition([FromBody] JobPosition position)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = _jobListingService.AddJobPosition(position);
                return Created(Request.Path.Value, result);
            } 
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
```

**Model**

```cs
    public class JobPosition
    {
        [Required]
        public long CompanyId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Exceed max length of 20.")]
        public string PositionType { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Exceed max length of 20.")]
        public string IhlType { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Exceed max length of 100.")]
        public string JobTitle { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        [Range(0, 1000, ErrorMessage = "Range for this field must be from 0 to 1000.")]
        public int NoOfPositions { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Exceed max length of 100.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Duration { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(2500, ErrorMessage = "Exceed max length of 2500.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string ScopeAndOutcome { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(2500, ErrorMessage = "Exceed max length of 2500.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string SkillsAndKnowledge { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(2500, ErrorMessage = "Exceed max length of 2500.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string RolesAndResponsibility { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Exceed max length of 20.")]
        public string JobFunction { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Exceed max length of 100.")]
        public string Department { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Exceed max length of 20.")]
        public string InternshipPlacementType { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime ClosingDate { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime MakePlacementDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool InDeclare { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
        public byte[] ResourceSumitId { get; set; }

        // submission checker
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Exceed max length of 20.")]
        public string ActionModeType { get; set; }

        // reviewer
        [MaxLength(1000, ErrorMessage = "Exceed max length of 1000.")]
        public string Remarks { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Exceed max length of 100.")]
        public string Reciptient { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Exceed max length of 100.")]
        public string RemarksBy { get; set; }
    }
```

The top mentioned above are the controller and model that I made for the web api.  I am not certainly sure why the data isn't correct...
I am not certain why I got an error of some kind and I am pretty sure my data structure is correct.

Comment: `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"` is the correct content-type for formData. You can't add `application/json` as content-type in the request headers when you are sending across form-data

Comment: The 400 Bad Request Error is an HTTP response status code that indicates that the server was unable to process the request sent by the client due to invalid syntax

Comment: @TomBombadil, I tried that earlier ago but couldn't make it work somehow, I did as well change to `text/plain` still the same issue.

Comment: I Think your sample payload not correct but for making sure can you please share your model with us (.net model)

Comment: @RaminAzali updated please check

Comment: You will need an appropriate parser as well on the server. Not sure what's your backend. But, with ExpressJS, we use `body-parser` or `express.json()`. They only parse JSON format and not formData. So, that can be the issue. If you are not sending across a file. I suggest that you try and send the data across in JSON format instead of formData and see if that fixes your problem. Also, log the error on server-side with stack trace and post it here. It will help SO users give you an appropriate solution.

Comment: @TomBombadil I am using `C#` as my back-end.

Comment: Have you sent across formData before to this server and has that call succeeded?

Comment: I dont see postingDate Field In your Dto Check Your Data payload with your model and make sure that its right status code 400 mean bad request as you know its almost happens when validation is not correct

Comment: @TomBombadil, No I haven't, this is my first time sending it to the server.

Comment: Then it can be a parser problem on the server. I don't code in `C#` so I can't help you in that respect. Checkout SO for what kind of a parser you need for multipart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope I write this DTO correctly.

```
public class JobPosition
{
    [Required]
    public long CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime postingDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Exceed max length of 20.")]
    public string PositionType { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Exceed max length of 20.")]
    public string IhlType { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Exceed max length of 100.")]
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [Range(0, 1000, ErrorMessage = "Range for this field must be from 0 to 1000.")]
    public int NoOfPositions { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Exceed max length of 100.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Duration { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(2500, ErrorMessage = "Exceed max length of 2500.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string ScopeAndOutcome { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(2500, ErrorMessage = "Exceed max length of 2500.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string SkillsAndKnowledge { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(2500, ErrorMessage = "Exceed max length of 2500.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string RolesAndResponsibility { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Exceed max length of 20.")]
    public string JobFunction { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Exceed max length of 100.")]
    public string Department { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Exceed max length of 20.")]
    public string InternshipPlacementType { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ClosingDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime MakePlacementDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool InDeclare { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public byte[] ResourceSumitId { get; set; }

    // submission checker
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Exceed max length of 20.")]
    public string ActionModeType { get; set; }

    // reviewer
    [MaxLength(1000, ErrorMessage = "Exceed max length of 1000.")]
    public string Remarks { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Exceed max length of 100.")]
    public string Reciptient { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Exceed max length of 100.")]
    public string RemarksBy { get; set; }
}
```

I am not sure this is the model you want. But, I found the field in your data that do not exists in your DTO, Please pay attention to your DTO.

Comment: Thank you, yeah, the postingDate shouldn't be included inside the model itself because it is handled automatically in the server.  I just remove it from the `formData` and everything works now, I didn't know as well that name should be the same as the model.  Thank you for the help!